# How to configure PostgreSQL certificates in Presto PostgreSQL connector?

Tags: postgresql, presto

We used to have Presto configured to connect to Postgresql and it was all working through and through. Recently we updated our DB to ask for certificates when accepting connections. With that change I am not sure how to specify certificates in the connector when it comes to defining it in the catalog.
 Do we specify it in the connection URL?

In the website it doesn't mention anything (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/postgresql.html) so I was hoping to get some help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should be configured via PostgreSQL JDBC connection URL that you provide in Presto PostgreSQL connector configuration file. Please refer to https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html for how to do this.

Comment: I currently have this setup: connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://{ip}:5432/dev?sslmode=verify-full&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.LibPQFactory&sslrootcert=/home/test/.postgresql/root.crt&sslcert=/home/test/.postgresql/postgresql.crt&sslkey=/home/test/.postgresql/postgresql.pk8 but presto is unable to understand LibPQFactory

Comment: Presto doesn't parse the JDBC url. It's being passed directly to the driver. 
BTW I guess it might be easier to troubleshoot this on `#troubleshooting` channel on [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).